# Excel - Complete a 10x10 Matrix with the values of its index(row number and column number) multiplied

Tags: excel, matrix

I'm trying in Excel to fill the blanks of a 10x10 matrix with the results of 2x2,2x3,2x4....3x4,3x5... etc. with the fewer steps possible. The values 1x2, 1x3, 1x3, etc are already present on the first row and first column.(indexes)

What formulas can I use to complete the rest of the matrix?

Thank you

Comment: This is a question that asks people to do you work for you. Naughty naughty, change it to ask what formula and **functions** can you use to complete the rest of the matrix and why. Then you can go and look at them and understand their power! 
  In this case the answer is just cell addresses with the dollar symbols (dollar fixes the row or column).

Comment: @Tyeth I got stuck. I tried to use the $ sign, but not as Foxfire and Burns and Burns. I tried to use one formula for vertical and one for horizontal. Geesh... I was out of focus last night. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure If I understood right but you can do it with a single formula:

[image]

My formula in B2 is `=$A2*B$1`. Just drag to right and then drag down.

Comment: Wow, I was so out of focus last night, I tried to do it with "$" and I couldn't figure it out so I thought its something more complex. Thanks a lot for your help! I really appreciate it.